# Set file manager view for Save As... dialog in Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, file-management, default-settings

How can I PERMANENTLY set the file manager default view for the Save As... dialog in Windows 10. I know how to change views in the regular file manager, but the dialogs do not seem to be affected by that setting.

Answer (score 0):

On the upper tab with Organize and New Folder, the 3rd icon from the right side has a dropdown if you click on ot and that will let you change the views.

[image: Screen Capture]

Comment: The question is about the Save As... dialog

Comment: The File Explorer save dialog?

Comment: Check the picture I attached to the answer, and see if I am mentioning the right thing

Comment: That drop down does not change the default view. I have edited my question to make it more clear. I ALWAYS want the dialog box to come up with the detail view. I don't want to have to change it every time.

Comment: Most likely if you can do it, it will be a change in the Registry