# In Windows 10, how do I change the default view (details, tiles, etc) for the Open and Save As dialog boxes?

Tags: windows-10, windows-registry

*(This question was [asked](https://superuser.com/questions/1456283/set-file-manager-view-for-save-as-dialog-in-windows-10) more than a year ago, with no answer)*

Some sites state Windows is supposed to automatically remember the last view settings in *Save As* and *Open*, but that isn't how things are working on my PC, as every time I go to *Open* or *Save As*, I get the Large icons view.

- I found several webpages on how to reset the Windows defaults for these dialogs by deleting corresponding registry keys, but nothing turns up in searches for instructions on how to set your own defaults, nor have I found any reference listing the registry subkeys for:

  ```
  HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\CIDSave
  HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\CIDOpen
  ```
- In Windows 7, holding <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> while clicking <kbd>[X]</kbd> [window close button] would save the current view as default, but this doesn't work in Windows 10

EDIT: A solution I had hoped to avoid (and assumed would not be necessary) is to use a script to send keystrokes to the dialogs. Even that option turns out to be more of a hack than it should be--there seem to be no shortcuts for switching to specific views, or even one for activating the 'Change your view' button, the one that displays the view options in a list. Are there one-shot keyboard shortcuts for setting the view, once you're in one of these boxes?

If not, it looks as though the series <kbd>Shift+Tab</kbd>, <kbd>Shift+F10</kbd>, <kbd>[V]</kbd> and then <kbd>[D]</kbd> will do the trick, crudely, so that the hassle of setting up the view each and every time could be condensed to a single keystroke, even if I can't get the script to fire automatically whenever one of these boxes gets opened.

[EDIT 2: After having deleted the registry Bags and BagMRU keys, and then going about my business for a couple of days, manually switching to Details view over and over again, here's what I get now when I run the script offered below by @Keith Miller ("CustomViews/FolderTypes in Use"):

FolderTypes in use:
Generic
Downloads
CompressedFolder
Music
Generic.SearchResults
ControlPanelCategory
Documents
HomeFolder

Note that I no longer have any 'CustomViews,' whereas prior to deleting those registry keys the script reported a few such. Again, there has been no change in behavior--my view selection in the dialog boxes doesn't stick, and I must manually reset it each time if I care to. ]

Answer (score 3):

The *Common Dialogs* provided by **Explorer** (*`Open`*/*`Save`*/*`Save As`* ) save their view settings in the same Registry location **Explorer** folder views are saved:

```powershell
HKCU\SOFTWARE\Classes\Local Settings\Software\Microsoft\Windows\Shell\Bags
```

[image: Screenshot1]

Each numbered subkey is associated with a particular folder via a lookup in the adjacent **`BagMRU`** key. Each folder can retain three different views:

- **`Shell`:** The view saved from **Explorer**
- **`ComDlg`:** is the modern dialog that displays the *Navigation Pane*
- **`ComDlgLegacy`:** displays the *Places Bar*

Each view will have a *GUID*-named subkey corresponding to the *`FolderType`* used by the folder. Here we see the **Pictures** *FolderType* : 
 [image]

---

If folder view settings are forgotten, the most likely cause is hitting the maximum of `5000` saved views:

- To determine the number of views saved, execute this **PowerShell** code:

  ```powershell
  ((gp 'HKCU:\Software\Classes\Local Settings\Software\Microsoft\Windows\Shell\BagMRU').Nodeslots).count
  ```

  - If this returns `5000`, you have to delete all saved views by deleting the following two registry keys:

    ```powershell
    HKCU\Software\Classes\Local Settings\Software\Microsoft\Windows\Shell\BagMRU
    HKCU\Software\Classes\Local Settings\Software\Microsoft\Windows\Shell\Bags
    ```
  - You can do this manually via `RegEdit` or by executing [PowerShell]:

    ```powershell
    sl 'HKCU:\Software\Classes\Local Settings\Software\Microsoft\Windows\Shell' 'BagMRU', 'Bags' | Remove-Item -Recurse
    ```

The first time a location is accessed via a Common Dialog, it will use the default view for the associated `FolderType`. This will be either:

- A user-specific custom default set by *Apply to Folders* and saved under **`HKCU\...\Streams\Defaults`**
- The machine-wide default view defined under `HKLM\...\FolderTypes`.

Subsequent to the initial display, the view should be saved and recalled from the *`Bag`* subkey associated with the folder.

- If you want the dialog view to match the default Explorer view, ensure you have saved your view preferences for that `FolderType` using *Apply to Folders*, after opening the folder in **Explorer** and setting your preferences: [image: Screenshot]
- To see what *`FolderTypes`* you've set via *Apply to Folders* and what *`FolderTypes`* used by one or more saved views, execute:

  ```powershell
  $Defaults    = 'HKCU:\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Streams\Defaults'
  $FolderTypes = 'HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\FolderTypes'
  $Bags        = 'HKCU:\Software\Classes\Local Settings\Software\Microsoft\Windows\Shell\Bags'

  If ( Test-Path $Defaults ) {
    Write-Host 'Custom Views saved for:'
    ForEach ( $FTID in (Get-Item  $Defaults).Property ) {
      Write-Host ( "`t" + (Get-ItemProperty "$FolderTypes\$FTID").CanonicalName )
    }
  } Else {
    Write-Host 'No custom views saved.'
  }
  Write-Host 'FolderTypes in use:'

  Get-ChildItem $Bags -Recurse | ? PsChildName -like '{*}' | select -expand PSChildName -unique | ForEach {
    If ( $_ -ne '{25CC242B-9A7C-4F51-80E0-7A2928FEBE42}' ) {
      Write-Host ( "`t" + (Get-ItemProperty "$FolderTypes\$_").CanonicalName )
    } Else {
      Write-Host "`tNetwork"
    }
  }
  ```

I'll post further troubleshooting if clearing current saved views doesn't fix your issue.

---

Use the following code to clear only dialog views while preserving **Explorer** views:

```powershell
$Bags = 'HKCU:\Software\Classes\Local Settings\Software\Microsoft\Windows\Shell\Bags'
$Bags | gci -Recurse | ? PSChildName -match 'ComDlg' | Remove-Item -Recurse 
gps explorer | spps
```

Comment: Very much appreciate the detailed response/background info/instructions--but: I've only had the computer a couple of weeks so the count returned by ((gp ....Nodeslots).count is just 876. Also, while my custom views 'stick' just fine in Explorer, the Open/Save As dialogs have *never* shown those views when opening the same folders. Should I try clearing the saved views anyway?

Comment: You could first try a more "surgical" deletion, removing only the dialog-related subkeys but leaving the Exlplorer views. Will ediy my answer to add that code.

Comment: No luck. Wound up deleteing the keys \BagMRU and \Bags keys just to make sure. Your script confirms there are no longer any "FolderTypes in use:" though I still see the items that were previously there under "Custom views saved for:" No change in behavior, boxes still default to Large tiles regardless of whether the folders they are browsing have views set in Explorer, and even after previously opening the boxes on those folders and customizing their views in the same application.

Comment: (PS tried to edit your post to correct a few little typos but those spelling changes were below the minimum character count for edits. Errors include "saveed," "presderving," and one other one I can't find again right now. Plus "ediy" directly above.)

Comment: Thanks. Visually  impaired here. Can't see whole words clearly. Combined with heavy, clumsy typing fingers, it can wreak havoc.

Comment: So, before we resort to ProcMon , can you run the CustomViews/FolderTypes in Use code and then post the results by editing your quesiton.